# Environment-specific routing in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'd like to create a scope in my routes.rb file to only route certain URLs when in the production environment. How do you use conditionals with Rails 3 routing? All I need to do is restrict those rules based on `Rails.env.production?` being true, but I'm not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`routes.rb` is Ruby file so this should work:

```
  if Rails.env.production?
    get "/bar" => 'welcome#index'
  else
    get "/foo" => 'welcome#index'
  end
```